# How to display value from input type="number"

Tags: php, input

I have a input field which holds the **quantity** of the item. If the user changes the quantity value I would like to update the value stored in the session. My problem is that I cannot get the "value".

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="quantityInput" size="1" maxlength="2" value="'.$cart_itemDisplay['quantity'].'">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" method="POST" name="refreshBtn"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
</form>
```

When I try to store the value:

```
$quantityOfItemToAdjust = $_POST['quantityInput'];
```

Full code:

```
echo '
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td data-th="Product">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src="img/movies/'.$imageName.'" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                            <h4 class="nomargin">'.$nameOfProduct.'</h4>
                                                            <p>'.$productDesc.'</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td data-th="Price">£'.$priceOfItem.'</td>
                                                <td data-th="Quantity">
                                                    <form method="post" action="tickets.php">
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="quantityInput" size="1" maxlength="2" value="'.$cart_itemDisplay['quantity'].'">

                                                    </form>
                                                    </td>
                                                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">1.99</td>
                                                <td class="actions" data-th="">

                                                    <form method="post" action="tickets.php">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" method="submit" name="refreshBtn"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                                                        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="'.$idOfItem.'"/>




                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>    
                                                    </form>


                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        ';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use submit instead of button and the form need an action.

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
<input type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="quantityInput" size="1" maxlength="2" value="'.$cart_itemDisplay['quantity'].'">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="refreshBtn" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

This shall work.

Comment: IE: your need to understand how forms work in html\php

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In my code I had it as submit I was just unsure if it should be submit or post if it was in the form method section. I've reverted it back to submit. I tried your changes but I still have no luck, I'm unsure to why.

Comment: @user3245390 its POST or GET for a method. submit is a type of form input -- perhaps update with what your actually using

Comment: `<button></button>` and `<input type="submit">` will do the same when placed inside a `<form></form>`

Comment: The METHOD should be either POST or GET, as said by Dagon. GET will display the variables in the URL, POST won't. So it's up to you. If you use the form action as POST, you must get it as post in the PHP code. You must set the method in the form, not in the button. The submit is used to trigger the form.

Comment: I edited my answer as there was something wrong in it, try again now

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried the change the same issue still persists. I should mention I think my mistake with the submit has side tracked people a bit from my actual problem. I've tried manually passing a value (1) and when I do that my code works no problem. It's just getting the value from the element. I'll add the actual unedited code to my main post now, I edited it slightly for readability which might be causing an issue, apologies for that.

Comment: I'm very confused, to what I'm doing wrong :/. I tried this code and it didn't work either <form action="temp.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name = "quantityInput33"  maxlength="2" value="1"></form>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['quantityInput33']))
  {
   echo $_POST['quantityInput33'];
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Is not set";
  }
  ?>